# WPF: Storyboard in style returning a "Cannot animate 'Color' on an immutable object instance."

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, user-controls, stackpanel

I have the following XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush"></SolidColorBrush>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}" x:Key="ColourChangingStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Brush}" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path='Stage'}" Value="1">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource Brush}"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" From="{StaticResource FirstColor}" To="{StaticResource FinishedColor}" Duration="0:0:10" BeginTime="0:0:0"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel x:Name="InfoPanel" Orientation="Vertical"  Margin="1,2" Style="{DynamicResource ColourChangingStyle}">
 ...
</StackPanel>
```

And I keep getting the same error that:

> Cannot animate 'Color' on an immutable object instance

which is the brush. I looked up the problem, and believe that it's something to do with the binding the brush to the `StackPanel` making it unavailable to alter later.

Is there any way around this, I literally have no clue what my other options for the same effect are without hardcoding colors in, and doing all the events in code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you can not animate a `Brush` in `Resources` with `Storyboard.Target`. But you can set the `Background` of your `Style` (you have done this already) and animate this property.

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                From="{StaticResource FirstColor}"
                To="{StaticResource FinishedColor}" 
                Duration="0:0:10" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your color state from code behind to check out is color Frozen or not to prevent that exception.

```
private void CheckAnimationFrozen()
{
    // ...
    // Frozen brush unable to begin animation
    if (CircleColor.IsFrozen)
    {
        CircleColor = new SolidColorBrush(CircleColor.Color);
    }
    
    // ...
}
```